# How to hide functions within classes in c#?

Tags: c#, constructor, method-hiding

I need to hide few methods inside a class based on the parameter that is passed to the constructor in c#. How would I do this?
Thanks in advance!

More Info:
I was part of this GUI development where they had a API with access to registers in a hardware. Now they are releasing a newer hardware so I need to support both old and new one which has a newer API(Mostly duplicate of old one with some old removed and some new registers added).

Moreover, I need to keep this only one class called "API" as we used it in many places. So the idea of using a newer API with a different name was ruled out.

Now finally, I got this idea of including the newer one into old one with just conditionally hiding the registry access methods.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'hide'?

Comment: Maybe you should use `private` modifier? As said @tzaman - what do you mean by 'hide'?

Comment: to make the methods inaccessible or remove it from the class.

Comment: @tzaman: make them private and not accessible from outside, i think

Comment: For eg. if the parameter is true then the methods should be accessible and if not the opposite.

Comment: It is impossible in C#. It doesn't support recompilation during runtime :)

Comment: Then just store your parameter inside some class-member variable and check its value on start of all possibly "hidden" methods. If the variable has specific value then, say, `throw new NotImplementedException();` otherwise process with actual method code.

Also _why_ do you need that? Maybe if you explain this we might suggest something better...

Comment: @Wojteq: Actually supports - via Reflection. Just I don't think OP will want to go this hard way...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by hiding methods?  Might be able to suggest alternate solutions

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev, I know it, but it wasn't the point of this question :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't toggle the visibility of members..... the best bet is to have different interfaces that hide the members.

```
public interface IName
{
   string Name { get; set; }
}


public interface INumber
{
   string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}


public class Worker : IName, INumber
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

So either use Worker through the IName or the INumber interface and it will hide the other members on the class....

Comment: Hi, thanks. But the thing is if I take interface to hide the methods, I need to do that conditionally(if the paramater passed = true to the constructor) then enable this interface or else use another interface. Is this doable in c#?

Comment: @Vikyboss - instead of invoking the constructor directly, you can have a factory function that creates the class for you and returns it as the appropriate interface depending on the parameter.

Comment: its not making much sense to me to do this with static typing.... are you using reflection or dynamic stuff?     because if you return a magically changing type based on parameter..... what's getting that type?  and how does it know what members to call?

Comment: Method call will only happen conditionally. As I will create a newer user module for the new one. And the modules will be instantiated based on the condition. Thus, calls will be only to the present function.

Comment: in which case, you don't need to 'hide' the methods, if the outside code know which methods to call based on certain conditions,  which BTW sounds like a bad design,  its more likely a better solution can be found using an OO abstraction and instances for the different cases

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking at a re-factor here.  Try making a base class with all the methods / properties that behave the same regardless of the parameter, then two child classes which behave differently.  Also have a look at the class factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to restructure the code into multiple classes or interfaces. You can't dynamically change the visibility level of class members based on a parameter value. Members are construction time information not run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change visibility of methods, but you can pass parameter to the single method and do  some logic depending on your parameter by using `switch` - `case`. But it depends on your method structure.

Try to review your class and change its design. Maybe you can find any design pattern that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may actually do something alike using [Dynamic code generation](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/28783/1954), although this is more like a hack than actual code that should be used in production.

Maybe if you explain *why* you need this then you may get more relevant answers.